# Why does Rashi comment on some verb-לו phrases and not others?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grammar-dikduk, rashi, pentateuch-chumash

A feature of *lashon hakodesh* (Biblical Hebrew) is that a verb is sometimes followed by "לו", inflected for the person, number, and gender of the [subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_%28grammar%29), without the "לו" indicating an object of the verb. This occurs frequently in *Tanach*, and also later (e.g. "בא לו אצל רבי דוסא בן הרכינס" in [*mishnayos Rosh Hashana* chapter 2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%98)). At some, but not all, of its appearances in *chumash*, *Rashi* comments on it.

Note that [Gesenius](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3AGesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar_%281910_Kautzsch-Cowley_edition%29.djvu/405) (FWIW) says that this "לו" has no specific meaning itself, but does change the meaning of the sentence slightly: it is there (in his words) "to give emphasis to the significance of the occurrence in question for a particular subject", namely for the [subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_%28grammar%29) of the verb (or more precisely for the [referent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/referent) of the subject of the verb).

My first question is: When *Rashi* comments on the presence of "לו" in *chumash*, is it:

- because he views such a construction as purely [pleonastic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) ([rhetorical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elocutio)) in general (i.e., bearing no connotation whatsoever, *not* like Gesenius), and wishes to explain its presence in that location, specifically, as *not* purely pleonastic but, rather, bearing the meaning he mentions; or
- because he views such a construction as purely pleonastic everywhere, and wishes to explain its presence in that location *b'derech d'rash*; or
- because he views such a construction, in general, as, *l'havdil*, Gesenius does (that the word is adding emphasis of the significance of the action to its subject) and merely wishes to explain in greater detail *how* or *why*, in that location, that act is particularly significant to its subject; or
- for some other reason?

And my second question, which can only really be answered once the first is (i.e., once we know why *Rashi* is commenting at all) is: Why does *Rashi* choose to comment on some of these and not on others? For example, he comments at [*B'reshis* 12:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8176/showrashi/true#v1), "לֶךְ **לְךָ** מֵאַרְצְךָ וּמִמּוֹלַדְתְּךָ וּמִבֵּית אָבִיךָ", but not at [*D'varim* 16:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9980/showrashi/true#v9), "שִׁבְעָה שָׁבֻעֹת תִּסְפָּר **לָךְ**".

Comment: Note that your example of what Rashi *doesn't* explain does have an explanation: That each individual has to count, and it's not an obligation on the community; some even say that a person can't fulfill his obligation through someone else, like Mishnah Brurah [489:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=189) (the question on Rashi remains)

Answer (score 1):

I would say in principal that Rashi would comment on it only in specific cases where he thinks that one might have some reasonable doubt about the Pshat on the Pasuk.

Comment: But why would I have doubt about one and not another? Either _lo_ is always pleonastic, so its presence always raises a question; or it's always for emphasis (as Gesenius says) or something, so its presence always raises a question; or it's always for emphasis or something, so its presence always never a question. Or perhaps it's always for emphasis and the explanation of that emphasis sometimes is clear and sometimes requires explanation? That's possible. Is that what you mean? Do you have an argument or source in support of it?